# Can we use Jetty8.x with Java 1.8?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jetty-8

I am developing an eclipse RCP application with Eclipse Juno (4.2.2) that comes with Jetty 8.1.3. I have bundled the product with Java SDK 1.8. The RCP application runs fine but Help -> Help Contents gives below error. (Note that this works fine if I try with java 1.7)

Does Jetty 8.x works with Java 8? If yes, could you please provide instructions on how to make it work with Java SDK 1.8?

```
HTTP ERROR: 500
Problem accessing /help/index.jsp. Reason: 

PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
referenced from required .class files
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You need Java 1.6 for Jetty8.
If you want to use Java 1.8, you need to upgrade to Jetty9.3 or higher.